# Roll hover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I searched on the internet a lot but I couldn't find any useful link. I am trying to develop a custom menu.

It needs to be an area-based rollover menu which changes depending on which part of the image is currently being hovered over by the user. The image and related link needs to change depending on what area of the image the user is hovering over. Check the below image:
[image: close box]

After clicking the next image would be below one,
[image: open box]

Lastly when I hover on any specific slice of pizza, the image should be changed accordingly. An example is the below image:

[image]

Is it possible with CSS3, JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, I have spent almost 6-7 hours today. But I wasn't even close to the solution.

Comment: Please post the code you have in your question.

Comment: The answer is - YES, it is possible with CSS3, JavaScript. Are you happy for now? Make your question more readable and understandable pls.

Comment: I used image map with jQuery flip method. But then the hovered image cover the main image. So the other slices couldn't be hover at all. Any hints?

Comment: mouse-events: none ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand @vals?

Comment: If your current problem is that the hovered image covers the main image, and blocks further hovers, then setting mouse-events: none on that image could solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

There's two different ways that I could think of. Since you tagged JQuery I'm assuming that's acceptable. `pageX` and `pageY` track mouse movements on screen and can be used to determine what area of the screen is being hovered over. Here's a fiddle I made to determine the coordinates: http://jsfiddle.net/cpk3mqxw/

```
$("#image").mousemove(function (e) {
mousex = e.pageX;
mousey = e.pageY;
$("#update").text("x: " + mousex + " y:" + mousey);
});
```

EDIT: For checking the coordinates, what you need to do is think of the page as a grid system, as per usual with JavaScript, and gauge that If mousex is more than 132 and less than 155 it must be over THIS part of the image. Again, a separate span tag with constantly updated x and y coordinates will be helpful.
a.e:

```
if(mouse x >= 102 && mousex <= 220 && mousey >= 26) {
//do this
}
```

It pays off in the end, but it is quite a bit of extra work. Another way is to use an image map.

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="image1" usemap="#one">
<map name="one">
<area coords="30, 50, 70, 100" href="gohere.html">
</map>
```

And if you'd like the area to be highlighted or styled you can use maphilight.js which you can find more information on here: http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/maphilight-image-map-mouseover-highlighting/

Comment: Bad idea to alert stuff on mousemove.

Comment: @Shikkediel You're right, I agree in practice it isn't the best idea and I went back and noted that it's best to throw it in a span tag. I definitely didn't mean to suggest that it would be the most effective method, just wanted to showcase functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. But it won't work if I try to bring a new image on hover as it will cover the main image(Google).

Comment: @ShahriarKabir Not quite sure what you mean by that? Maybe I can help?

Answer (score 0):

A great solution for your problem would be to create a sprite containing an image of your pizza with one slice missing on each image. Then, you create a div the size of one pizza image:

```
   <div id="myPizza"></div>
```

Then, you can check X and Y position of the mouse over this div using a script similare to this one http://coursesweb.net/javascript/get-mouse-coordinates-inside-div-image_s2

Then, depending where the cursor is on your image, you can put a class with the right background position on it. I suggest you this to create your classes: http://www.spritecow.com/

Hope it helped, simple script with sprites!

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: It's my pleasure, if you need some more advice or if you don't understand it properly tell me, I did it in the past on a website where a slice of bread was being eaten on scroll and it worked very well with the sprite formula.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this problem.

I used `<map>` and `<area>` to define each of the areas (pizza slices) I need. 
Then I added the `onclick()` and `onmouseover()` event handler to each area to call a function to change the picture.

**HTML**

```
<area shape="circle" coords="200,250,25" onmouseover = "changePic('newImage.png')" />
<img src='start_pic.png' name='mainPic' />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function changePic(img){
   mainPic.src = img;
}
```

[**PREVIEW LINK**](http://www.tapetenwechsel.me/rollfinished/)

Comment: I also think if I used sprite, it would be better for loading the images. But I don't know how I can use sprite inside area tag, do you know?